# TemplateDoesNotExist while the file exists and permissions are correct

Tags: django, html, django-templates

I'm trying to extend from a template, and I keep getting the same **TemplateDoesNotExist** error. All other pages, that don't extend the base template work (they just have some dummy html)

I did a ls -l and the file exists and all the permissions are idential:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 atrus users 1625 Mar 13 13:05 base.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 atrus users 4096 Mar 13 10:50 css
drwxr-xr-x 2 atrus users 4096 Mar 13 10:51 img
-rw-r--r-- 1 atrus users  136 Mar 13 13:14 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 atrus users  407 Mar 12 12:16 login.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 atrus users  662 Mar 12 03:21 register.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 atrus users   59 Mar 12 02:41 temp.html
```

So it's not a permissions issue, and the file (base.html exists)

My view that I'm calling (index) is simply:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('menu/index.html')
```

and my index.html is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<p>here be content <p>
{% endblock content %}
```

with the error occurring at the very first line.

My TEMPLATE_DIRS of settings.py is:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/atrus/Dropbox/workspace/menu/menu/templates'
)
```

Comment: What does `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your `settings.py` look like?

Comment: are you supposed to have `.../menu/menu/...` in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS`? Not sure if that's a typo or the actual setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have a `menu` directory within you templates folder (assuming that's where you did the `ls`). Have you tried just doing `return render_to_response('index.html')`

Also, as stated in my comment, is your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` the correct file path? I'm not sure if you accidentaly duplicated "menu"

Comment: You're right, it's in the subfolder, and that's not in the TEMPLATE_DIRS directly.

And yes, the menu/menu is correct. Just an artifact of creation that really isn't a big enough deal for me to change when working on my little project.

Answer (score 1):

When you leave out the comment, your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting is just this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/atrus/Dropbox/workspace/menu/menu/templates')
```

which is actually a single string, not a tuple. You need a comma:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/atrus/Dropbox/workspace/menu/menu/templates',)
```